# What is the number of lone pairs of central atom when it has an odd number of electrons?

Tags: electronic-configuration, bond

What does it mean in asking the number of lone pairs of central atom when it has an odd number of electrons? 
As lone pairs means the no. of non bonding **pairs** of electrons does it exclude the one odd electron if present in the central atom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when there is an odd number of valence electrons left on the the central atom?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39001/what-to-do-when-there-is-an-odd-number-of-valence-electrons-left-on-the-the-cent)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a tricky bit of chemical terminology that may not have a lot of practical relevance, so I wouldn't get too hung up on this, if I were you. Technically, I would say that you are correct in that lone pairs should be pairs of electrons, as this is how [the IUPAC defines them](http://goldbook.iupac.org/L03618.html).

Comment: I second that… a lone electron is typically called a “localized radical”, and is not considered a lone pair (see [here](http://www.angelfire.com/sc3/iupacstructures/old/preferredstyles/graphiccharges/) for an example)