The MO diagram of chlorine dioxide?
I have tried to draw a MO diagram of chlorine dioxide using carbon dioxide but I am severly struggling - I have only managed to do pi molecular orbitals but I am struggling on sigma molecular orbitals and nonbonding electrons. So can someone provide me a MO diagram for Chlorine dioxide
note: I am aware that there is a question about this on stack exchange but they simply just drew MO in Chlorine dioxide and gave minimal explanation whereas I am asking for a MO diagram.

You mean this one: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108427/clo2-molecular-orbital-diagram ?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98942/hybridisation-of-clo2

yes but they don't provide an insightful diagram - an actual MO diagram
